# Significance range on ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, significance

So there is a graph that i did with this code

```
# create the barplot with significance astexrisks
ggplot(data = means_df, aes(x = FtrialType, y = emmean, fill = Fdev)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL),
               width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
 labs(x = "Trial Type", y = "Estimated Marginal Mean") +
 scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors, name = "Deviation") +
 theme_classic() +
 theme(legend.position = "top",
       axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14),
       text = element_text(size = 15),
       axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", angle = 0, face = 'bold', size = 14))
```

and i wanted to put the significance asterisks for the Agreement more - Agreement same ; Agreement same - Agreement less ; Disagreement more - Disagreement same ; Disagreement same - Disagreement less,
I tried adding this :

```
geom_signif(     data = means_df,     comparisons = list(c("Agreement", "Disagreement")),     map_signif_level = TRUE   )
```

but it does not give me what i want,

```
# create the emmeans 
means <- emmeans(fit1.3, ~ FtrialType*Fdev)
# create the contrasts
contrasts <- data.frame(emm1$contrasts)
# convert means and contrasts to data frames
means_df <- as.data.frame(means)
contrasts_df <- as.data.frame(contrasts)
```

here are the contrasts :

```
> dput(contrasts_df)
structure(list(contrast = c("Agreement more - Disagreement more", 
"Agreement more - Agreement same", "Agreement more - Disagreement same", 
"Agreement more - Agreement less", "Agreement more - Disagreement less", 
"Disagreement more - Agreement same", "Disagreement more - Disagreement same", 
"Disagreement more - Agreement less", "Disagreement more - Disagreement less", 
"Agreement same - Disagreement same", "Agreement same - Agreement less", 
"Agreement same - Disagreement less", "Disagreement same - Agreement less", 
"Disagreement same - Disagreement less", "Agreement less - Disagreement less"
), estimate = c(13.9891915935062, 4.86211599402995, 15.8193509988165, 
8.24054873324312, 17.2804916596388, -9.12707559947629, 1.83015940531028, 
-5.74864286026312, 3.29130006613258, 10.9572350047866, 3.37843273921316, 
12.4183756656089, -7.5788022655734, 1.4611406608223, 9.03994292639571
), SE = c(0.711188148088369, 0.707389428812583, 0.703854330745656, 
0.706270503412219, 0.705520818644373, 0.716550453607522, 0.709653090545637, 
0.715844313658603, 0.713583826614235, 0.710576555442431, 0.712675325487783, 
0.711948862603882, 0.709004112269533, 0.707981641874268, 0.711517456479972
), df = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf), z.ratio = c(19.670169744966, 6.87332294771701, 
22.4753195480912, 11.6676948753068, 24.4932413090836, -12.7375198124925, 
2.57894939047346, -8.03057697124453, 4.61235238717352, 15.4202033839467, 
4.74049348755105, 17.4427916356097, -10.6893629168293, 2.06381150922807, 
12.7051597175398), p.value = c(1.94239015196788e-85, 8.55318355795017e-12, 
5.42856513627015e-111, 3.49510717863204e-31, 2.61539176658542e-131, 
9.1460221266394e-37, 0.0106179969126748, 1.45522989231506e-15, 
4.59389162324955e-06, 3.59180158263531e-53, 2.66497881816471e-06, 
1.46446360966568e-67, 1.90253973268146e-26, 0.0390355914089589, 
1.18620637258798e-36)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
15L))
```

If anyone has any idea or input it would be amazing! Thanks !!  ☺️[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLvXm.png)

I tried this :

```
ggplot(data = means_df, aes(x = FtrialType, y = emmean, fill = Fdev)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  labs(x = "Trial Type", y = "Estimated Marginal Mean") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors, name = "Deviation") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14),
        text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", angle = 0, face = 'bold', size = 14)) +
  geom_signif(
    data = means_df,
    comparisons = list(c("Agreement", "Disagreement")),
    map_signif_level = TRUE
  )
```

It gave me a NS comparison between Agreement and Disagreement
then :

```
#asterisks 
# Create a new data frame for the asterisks
asterisks_df <- data.frame(
  FtrialType = c("Agreement", "Disagreement", "Agreement", "Disagreement", "Agreement", "Disagreement"),
  Fdev = c("more", "more", "same", "same", "less", "less"),
  ypos = c(-2,13, -2, 13, -2, 13), # Adjust these values based on your specific plot
  asterisks = c("***", "**", "***", "**", "***", "**") # Add the significance levels as asterisks
)
# Add the asterisks to the plot using geom_text()
p <- ggplot(data = means_df, aes(x = FtrialType, y = emmean, fill = Fdev)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  labs(x = "Trial Type", y = "Estimated Marginal Mean") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors, name = "Deviation") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14),
        text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", angle = 0, face = 'bold', size = 14)) +
  geom_text(data = asterisks_df, aes(x = FtrialType, y = ypos, label = asterisks),
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 4, fontface = "bold")

# Print the plot
print(p)
```

It gave me asterisks created manually for each bar, when what i want is brackets with significance asterisks for the contrasts

Thanks !!!